# Problema al mostrar el valor de una variable en la pantalla

Tags: c++

Tengo un código que debe calcular el movimiento uniforme acelerado de un cuerpo que luego voy a usar para renderizar el movimiento en un archivo de video. El problema es que al calcular la posición y velocidad del cuerpo en determinado tiempo, el valor resulta siendo cero. Aquí está mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class body
{
public:
    float initial_position = 0;
    float initial_speed = 0;
    float position = 0;
    float size = 0;
    float speed = 0;
    float aceleration = 0;

    void initializeData()
    {
        initial_position = 0;
        initial_speed = 10;

        size = 2;
        aceleration = 10;
    }

    void update(float time)
    {
        position = initial_position + (initial_speed * time) + ((aceleration * (time * time)) / 2);
        speed = initial_speed + (aceleration * time);

        system("clear");
        std::cout << "Time: " << time << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Position: " << position << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Speed: " << speed << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float time;
    body body00;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> time; 
        body00.update(time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No uses funciones de inicialización, usa constructores:

```
class body
{
public:
    float initialPosition = 0;
    float initialSpeed = 0;
    float position = 0;
    float size = 0;
    float speed = 0;
    float aceleration = 0;

    body(float position, float speed, float size, float acceleration) :
        initialPosition(position),
        initialSpeed (speed),
        size(size),
        aceleration(acceleration)
    {
    }

    ...
```

De esta manera, al carecer el objeto `body` de constructor por defecto, el compilador se habría negado a construirlo sin datos y habrías visto el error en tiempo de compilación.

Las funciones de inicialización sólo son convenientes cuando se necesita una inicialización en dos pasos (no es tu caso) o cuando se necesita reiniciar el estado de un objeto (tampoco es tu caso y el objeto es suficientemente sencillo como para que salga a cuenta crear uno nuevo).

Comment: No es la respuesta exacta, pero es un buen consejo. Voy a ponerlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

No les pasa que lo solucionan luego de preguntar, y que aparte era algo demasiado simple? Lo siento jaja. No había ejecutado el método initializeData:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class body
{
public:
    float initialPosition = 0;
    float initialSpeed = 0;
    float position = 0;
    float size = 0;
    float speed = 0;
    float aceleration = 0;

    void initializeData()
    {
        initialPosition = 0;
        initialSpeed = 10;

        size = 2;
        aceleration = 10;
    }

    void update(float time)
    {
        position = initialPosition + (initialSpeed * time) + ((aceleration * (time * time)) / 2);
        speed = initialSpeed + (aceleration * time);

        system("clear");
        std::cout << "Time: " << time << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Position: " << position << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Speed: " << speed << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float time;
    body body00;
    body00.initializeData();

    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> time; 
        body00.update(time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```